# Unable to conditionally test for presence of a plugin command & invoke it

Tags: autocmd, plugin-system, filetype-tex, plugin-vim-plug

I have the following code in my `vimrc`

```
if exists(":Goyo")
    augroup LatexGoyo
        autocmd!
        autocmd BufReadPost,BufNewFile *.tex Goyo
    augroup END
else
    augroup LatexColumnSet
        autocmd FileType tex setlocal columns=100
    augroup END
endif
```

The idea is to check for the presence of the `Goyo` command provided by the [`goyo.vim`](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim) plugin, and then invoke it upon opening any `tex` file. If this plugin is not available/installed, then I'd like to set the columns to 100.

However, with these settings in my `vimrc`, when opening a `tex` file, the `Goyo` command is not executed.

What am I doing wrong, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, your vimrc file is executed before any plugins are loaded. You can check the order of what source files are loaded by issueing the `:scriptnames` command.

The usual way to fix this *problem* is to execute the test inside a `VimEnter` autocommand, something like this:

```
function s:init()
   " do your test here!
endfun

augroup custom_vimrc
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * call s:init
augroup end
```

Comment: Another possibility is to do that from a `~/.vim/after/plugin/*.vim` which runs after normal plugins are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- Move the check to after plugins have been loaded, e.g. by hooking into the `VimEnter` event, as outlined by @ChristianBrabandt's answer.
- Force early loading of the plugin:

```
runtime! plugin/goyo.vim    " Try loading the plugin.
if exists(":Goyo")
    " ...
```